# android Studio gradle error hash string 21

Tags: android

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "de.ts.prosper"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

Hi :)

Android Studio put this error message -
failed to find target with hash-string android-21

What is wrong? SDK 21 is installed in SDK and 23 also

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "de.tetzisoft.prosper"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
}
```

Now it Looks like this and it doesn't work - ???

Failed to sync gradle Project ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your compile version should be the same as buildToolsVersion "23.0.1".
Please change it to 23.

Also in dependencies set     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'

Comment: Where can I Change it - just in the build.gradle file? Or anywhere else?

Comment: yes, all is int this file, just change 21 to 23 and it should work. You can keep targetSdkVersion as 21, but I recommend you to staya up-to-date

Comment: Now it Looks like this and it doesn't run

Answer (score 0):

I've just run your code and it works. You should maybe clean and rebuild the project.

Comment: Now it seems to run - thank you for your help I have to clean it